# Routing each player request to different server/ip address

Tags: web, dns, routes, load-balancing

I've a particular use case where I want to route each incoming request to a different server machine. Its a simulation program where each person will get his server machine to simulate his work on. I've made a block diagram of my requirement
[block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8rM5.png)

It's a 2 part question:

1. what's the terminology for this? Is it dynamic dns or load balancing (round robin)
2. how to implement it?
   Ofcourse I won't be able to implement it by myself, what sort of people/devs do I need for this implementation?

Comment: If users get their own dedicated machine, how would you relate/identify each user to the machine they're assigned to - based on request headers, cookies, subdomain, URI? Is the subdomain same for all users? If the server machine doesn't care which user it is, then you could use simple load balancing (round robin/least connection/session stickiness). Is your application working yet, or planning phase?

Comment: Will you run this simulation from client machines  that you control, or requests may come from anywhere?

Comment: what is the purpose of routing to the different IPs (reserving resources for the user; spreading the load across the cluster; isolating resources in the multitenant environment)? what is the planned interaction with the reserved resource (RDP/VNC session; interactive coding pane with code execution on the backend; ...)? Solution may vary significantly depends on the requirements and use-cases (maybe you even don't need what you think you need). Find an architect which will figure out requirements and create a design, don't jump into development right away.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. what's the terminology for this? Is it dynamic dns or load balancing (round robin)
> 2. how to implement it? Ofcourse I won't be able to implement it by myself, what sort of people/devs do I need for this implementation?

So there are two things:

- DNS is used for name / address resolution. It isn't specifically used for distributing requests to different servers.
- Normally you will have a load balancer that routes a request to a server based on some criteria. Load balancing has nothing to do with name resolution.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)

See: https://www.linode.com/products/nodebalancers/

The persons you need for implementation depends on what kind of application you're developing.

Without more information, it is hard to comment, but if you're speaking just about the load balancing part, you need someone who can understands the platform you're using (Linode, AWS etc), so that he can architect your solution to behave the same way as it would if it were just on a single machine, but have the benefit of scalability.